# How can I sort taxonomy term using attachment in drupal view

Tags: input-formats

I would like to sort taxonomy term using attachment in view like this (A B C ...). When I created sort for Taxonomy term using contextual filter, the Alphabetical(radio button) was disabled under "When the filter value is NOT available" section for taxonomy term. This radio button already enabled for content: title but it was disabled for taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

If u are creating view of taxonomy term, then it gives you option for sorting taxonomy term using name, However if u are using content type view and u want to show attachment, then add Global:View in attachment fields, and choose a view of taxonomy, with passing contextual filters in it.